# Share workflow to set up CI with Node and Yarn

Tags: github-actions

I'm working on a monorepo with Lerna and I want to migrate from CircleCI to GitHub Actions.

My actions are working perfectly but I saw that I had similar tasks to set up tests and lint so I wanted to use shared workflow and this is where I have an issue.

Here are my workflows:

```yaml
// .github/workflows/ci-setup.yml

name: "[CI] Setup"
on:
  workflow_call

jobs:
  build:
    name: Setup
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: szenius/set-timezone@v1.2
        with:
          timezoneLinux: "Europe/Paris"
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version-file: '.node-version'
      - name: Setup
        run: cp packages/mobile/env.sample.json packages/mobile/env.json && cp packages/mobile-pro/env.sample.json packages/mobile-pro/env.json
      - name: Run install
        uses: Borales/actions-yarn@v4.2.0
        with:
          cmd: install # will run `yarn install` command
```

```yaml
// .github/workflows/ci-test.yml
name: "[CI] Test"
on: [push]

concurrency:
  group: ci-test-${{ github.ref }}
  cancel-in-progress: true

jobs:
  setup:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/ci-setup.yml
  build:
    needs: setup
    name: Test on the monorepo
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Test
        uses: Borales/actions-yarn@v4.2.0
        with:
          cmd: test-ci # will run `yarn test-ci` command
```

```yaml
// .github/workflows/ci-lint.yml
name: "[CI] Lint"
on: [push]

concurrency:
  group: ci-test-${{ github.ref }}
  cancel-in-progress: true

jobs:
  setup:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/ci-setup.yml
  build:
    needs: setup
    name: Lint on the monorepo
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Lint
        uses: Borales/actions-yarn@v4.2.0
        with:
          cmd: lint # will run `yarn lint` command
```

The issue is that during `yarn lint` and `yarn test-ci`, `yarn` is not installed because it's run inside a different container than the test and lint container

How can I keep the same container? Or is it not possible and I should copy-paste the setup steps?

Comment: You need a _custom action_ to set up the container for the other steps, not a _reusable workflow_ that runs in its own container. Here's an [example](https://github.com/textbook/take-action/tree/nodejs) I wrote, [in use](https://github.com/textbook/build-info/blob/971ab351c3d94242c32ea2dcb9a6e326f44001e3/.github/workflows/push.yml#L14-L16). Also FWIW `Borales/actions-yarn` seems totally pointless, just `run: yarn lint`.

Comment: A reusable workflow runs its own job, which means its own container

Comment: Okay TY, I did remove `Borales/actions-yarn`! But I don't understand your example, how does it work? Launching the `nodejs.yml` as steps won't work, no? On my side, I did this inside the `steps` : `- uses: ./.github/workflows/ci-setup.yml` and I have this error : `Error: Can't find 'action.yml', 'action.yaml' or 'Dockerfile' under '/home/runner/work/front/front/.github/workflows/ci-setup.yml'. Did you forget to run actions/checkout before running your local action?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I fix it, I create a folder outside `workflows` for more clarity

```
// .github/ci-setup/action.yml

name: "[CI] Setup"
description: This is here to setup the CI

runs:
  using: 'composite'
  steps:
    - uses: szenius/set-timezone@v1.2
      with:
        timezoneLinux: "Europe/Paris"
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set Node.js
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version-file: '.node-version'
    - name: Setup
      shell: bash
      run: cp packages/mobile/env.sample.json packages/mobile/env.json && cp packages/mobile-pro/env.sample.json packages/mobile-pro/env.json
    - name: Yarn install
      shell: bash
      run: yarn install
```

And then I did this inside my workflow

```
// .github/workflows/ci-lint.yml

name: "[CI] Lint"
on: [push]

concurrency:
  group: ci-lint-${{ github.ref }}
  cancel-in-progress: true

jobs:
  build:
    name: Lint on the monorepo
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Setup
        uses: ./.github/ci-setup
      - name: Launch lint with lerna
        run: yarn lint
```